# Realtek LAN Driver Installation Help

Tags: command-line, networking, drivers, 18.04, realtek

I'm using Ubuntu CLI 18.04 version and I'm facing issue when installing Realtek LAN driver.... My motherboard is B460I chipset. This is what I've tried and please help. THANK YOU!!

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (open terminal)
- cd Ubuntu (enter the folder which puts the additional functions)
- `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` (extract and install all .deb files in Ubuntu folder)
- `cd r8125-9.005.06` (enter LAN driver folder)
- `sudo chmod 777 autorun.sh` (give authority to autorun.sh, if you ignore this step, autorun.sh will not be found)
- `sudo ./autorun.sh` (run autorun.sh to install LAN driver)

But I get the attached error and cannot install.

[image: IMAGE HERE]

Comment: Please never ever do `chmod 777` on any file. This is a high security risk.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! @paladin